# Prolog Exists Function

Tags: prolog

I need to write in prolog these first order statements.  How are they to be written? red(X) should return false, green(X) should return false, and green(X) or red(X) should return true

[image]

I have this code already:

```
% Assigning Facts

apple(a).
apple(b).
orange(c).
pear(d).
carrot(e).
onion(f).
pepper(g).
% Assigning Rules

red(X) :- apple(X).
green(X) :- apple(X).

fruit(X) :- apple(X).
fruit(X) :- orange(X).
fruit(X) :- pear(X).

vegetable(X) :- carrot(X).
vegetable(X) :- pepper(X).

tasty(X) :- fruit(X).
tasty(X) :- carrot(X).
tasty(X) :- not(onion(X)).

vegetable(X) :- not(tasty(X)).
```

Comment: tasty/1 and vegetable/1 will not work when the argument is unbound, therefor they can also not be used in the "exists" solution below.

Comment: Your first two lines say that every apple is both red and green. Probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the 'exists' method in Prolog that you already know of?

How about:

```
red(X).               % ∃x Red(x)
green(X).             % ∃x Green(x)
(red(X) ; green(X)).  % ∃x Red(x) v Green(x)
```

Prolog will enumerate bindings of `X` which satisfy each call, or [fail trying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure). If you just wanted to test their existence and not collect bindings, you can ignore the variable and cut after the first binding, like so:

```
red(_), !.
```

You've also asked how to test if something is exclusively red or green, but not both. Try this:

```
((\+ red(X), green(X)) ; (red(X), \+ green(X)).  % ∃x Red(x) ⊻ Green(x)
```

Where `⊻` means [exclusive-or (XOR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

Comment: when I query red(X). I get a in my case, I would like it to return false if it is red(X). and if it is green(X). . Only if it is red(x) or green(x) it should be true

Comment: Then you want `((\+ red(X), green(X)) ; (red(X), \+ green(X)))`.

Comment: can you please explain what that is doing exactly please, as I am a newbie in prolog

Comment: That gives me:  

red(X).
X = a

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by Prolog enumerating bindings for `X`: a solution to the predicate `red(X)` is the individual `a`, meaning `∃x Red(x)` is true, when x is `a`. If Prolog couldn't find anything to bind to `X`, then the predicate `red(X)` would fail, and may be interpreted as false (as per _negation as failure_).